# Add an autogenerated id to h1/h2/h3's elements in questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request

I'm trying link to the *second* part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70849216/5783745) answer.

Is there any way to link to that specific h3 "*If you're having problems with vips on heroku..*"?

I tried looking for an `id` on that element:

[image]

If it's not possible to link to a section of a question or answer, could that be made possible by adding id's to h1/h2/h3's elements?

#### Example

Current:

```
<h3>If you're having problems with vips on heroku..</h3>
```

Autogenerated id (for demonstration):

```
<h3 id="if-youre-hav">If you're having problems with vips on heroku..</h3>
```

Then the link could be:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849182/could-not-open-library-vips-42-could-not-open-library-libvips-42-dylib#if-youre-hav
```

Comment: Interestingly, this was enabled on SO/SE for a couple/few weeks about a year ago. It is a capability which is available in Articles. Note: as of the last time I looked at the auto-generated IDs, the code would need a bit of work in order to be viable in general on posts, due to not containing the post's ID in the generated IDs (and not adding the post ID to any user-supplied `id` attribute).

Comment: Yes, it would be nice with more fine-grained linking, e.g. into [the feature list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) or [the glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/63550). But why restrict it to headlines? Examples are list elements, code sections, and a particular line in a code section.

Comment: @PeterMortensen > *why restrict it to headlines?*. Now that's ambition! Yes, on other elements would be great. GitHub readme's have some nice default behaviours (e.g. click on header to get link *including* anchor). But there's no reason SO couldn't lift the standard further still!